# PHP, Is using an object to build an SQL statement a bad practice?

Tags: php, oop

Is using an object to build up SQL Statements overkill?

Is defining a bare String enough for a SQL statement?

This is my PHP and SQL code:

```
class SQLStatement  {
private $table;
    private $sql;

    const INNER_JOIN = 'INNER JOIN';
    const LEFT_JOIN = 'LEFT JOIN';
    const RIGHT_JOIN = 'RIGHT JOIN';
    const OUTER_JOIN = 'OUTER JOIN';

    public function __construct($table) {
        $this->setTable($table);
    }

    public function setTable($table) {
        $this->table = $table;
    }

    public function buildFromString($string) {
        $this->sql = $sql;
    }

    public function select(array $columns) {
        $sql = 'SELECT ';
        $columns = implode(',', $columns);
        $sql .= $columns;
        $sql .= " FROM $this->table";

        $this->sql = $sql;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Setting up INSERT sql statement
     *
     * @param array $records The records to insert.The array keys must be the columns, and the array values must be the new values
     * @return object Return this object back for method chaining
     */
    public function insert(array $records) {
        $columns = array_keys($records);
        $values = array_values($records);
        $values = array_map('quote',$values);
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO ';
        $sql .= $this->table . '('. implode(',', $columns) . ')';
        $sql .= ' VALUES ' . '(' . implode(',', $values) . ')';

        $this->sql = $sql;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Setting up UPDATE sql statement
     *
     * @param array $records The records to update. The array keys must be the columns, and the array values must be the new records
     * @return object Return this object back for method chaining
     */
    public function update(array $records, $where) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE ' . $this->table . ' SET ';
        $data = array();
        foreach ($records as $column => $record) {
            $data[] = $column . '=' . quote($record);
        }
        $sql .= implode(', ', $data);
        $this->sql = $sql;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Setting up DELETE sql statement
     * @return object Return this object back for method chaining
     */
    public function delete($where=null) {
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . $this->table;
        $this->sql = $sql;
        if (isset($where)) {
            $this->where($where);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Setting up WHERE clause with equality condition. (Currently only support AND logic)
     * @param  array  $equalityExpression Conditional equality expression. The key is the column, while the value is the conditional values
     * @return object                     Return this object back for method chaining
     * 
     */ 
    public function where(array $equalityExpression) {
        if (!isset($this->sql)) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException('You must use SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE first before where clause');
        }
        $where = ' WHERE ';
        $conditions = array();
        foreach ($equalityExpression as $column => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $value = array_map('quote', $value);
                $conditions[] = "$column IN (" . implode(',', $value) . ')';
            }
            else {
                $value = quote($value);
                $conditions[] = "$column = $value";
            }
        }
        $where .= implode(' AND ', $conditions);
        $this->sql .= $where;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Setting up WHERE clause with expression (Currently only support AND logic)
     * @param  array  $expression Conditional expression. The key is the operator, the value is array with key being the column and the value being the conditional value
     * @return object             Return this object back for method chaining
     */
    public function advancedWhere(array $expression) {
        if (!isset($this->sql)) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException('You must use SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE first before where clause');
        }
        if (!is_array(reset($expression))) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid format of expression');
        }
        $where = ' WHERE ';
        $conditions = array();
        foreach ($expression as $operator => $record) {
            foreach ($record as $column => $value) {
                $conditions[] = $column . ' ' . $operator . ' ' . quote($value);
            }
        }
        $where .= implode(' AND ', $conditions);
        $this->sql .= $where;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Setting up join clause (INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, or OUTER JOIN)
     * @param  array  $tables <p>Tables to join as the key and the conditions array as the value (Currently only support ON logic)</p>
     *                        <p>Array example : array('post'=>array('postid'=>'post.id'))</p>
     * @param  string $mode   The mode of join. It can be INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, or OUTER JOIN
     * @return object         Return this object back for method chaining
     */
    public function join(array $joins, $mode = self::INNER_JOIN) {
        if (!isset($this->sql) && strpos($this->sql, 'SELECT')) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException('You must have SELECT clause before joining another table');
        }
        if (!is_array(reset($joins))) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid format of the join array.');
        }
        $Conditions = array();
        foreach ($joins as $table => $conditions) {
            $join = ' ' . $mode . ' ' . $table . ' ON ';
            foreach ($conditions as $tbl1 => $tbl2) {
                $Conditions[] = $tbl1 .  ' = ' . $tbl2;
            }
            $join .= implode(' AND ', $Conditions);
        }
        $this->sql .= $join;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Setting up GROUP BY clause
     * @param  array  $columns The columns you want to group by
     * @param  string $sort    The type of sort, ascending is the default
     * @return object          Return this object back for method chaining
     */
    public function groupBy(array $columns, $sort = 'ASC') {
        if (!isset($this->sql)) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException('You must use SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE first before group by clause');
        }
        $groupBy = ' GROUP BY ' . implode(',', $columns) . ' ' . $sort;
        $this->sql .= $groupBy;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Setting up HAVING clause with expression
     * @param  expression  $expression Conditional expression. The key is the operator, the value is an array with key being the column and the value being the conditional value
     * @return object             Return this object back for method chaining
     */
    public function having($expression) {
        if (!isset($this->sql) && strpos($this->sql, 'GROUP BY') === FALSE) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException('You must have SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE and have GROUP BY clause first before where clause');
        }
        if (!is_array(reset($expression))) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid format of expression');
        }
        $having = ' HAVING ';
        $conditions = array();
        foreach ($expression as $operator => $record) {
            foreach ($record as $column => $value) {
                $conditions[] = $column . ' ' . $operator . ' ' . $value;
            }
        }
        $having .= implode(' AND ', $conditions);
        $this->sql .= $having;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Return the SQL statement if this object is supposed to be string
     * @return string The sql statement
     */
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->sql;
    }
}
```

The disadvantage I found is when I need to use prepared statement since prepared statements contains placeholders.

Should I add a feature to my SQL Statement Object to do prepared statements?  When should using prepared statements good practice?

Comment: i think you should to do because prepared statements have many advantages  read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: It's overkill if you measured that it is overkill . If it helps you to write less code, and you can't notice significant changes on performance, I guess it is ok to use it. What would I do, is to check is there any already existing well tested class/library/framework with similar functionality. You can check Doctrine as suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not overkill or overengineering to use objects or prepared statements, they are good practice.

The goal is to make something versatile and re-usable, and it looks like you are heading on the right track.

However, many people have done this already, and you may be better off using an existing solution.

Some of the top ones are:

[Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

[Propel](http://propelorm.org/)

and I used to personally use:

[Idiorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm)

And if I am not mistaken, all three are built on PDO, and use prepared statements.

If you wanted to make your own solution for this, PDO and prepared statements are a very good idea, if not a must.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Good ? Many says that most ORMs are bad since its Active-record Pattern